# Extract Value From Text And Convert Row To Column

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

`tbl1` Is

```
ID | TXT                                                                                                   
-- | -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | Material discharged in hopper: Dest: FURNACE; ; 312 - CALCINE DOLOMIT: 1505kg;                        
 2 | Dest: FURNACE; AUTO; 312 - CALCINE DOLOMIT: 1505kg;                                                   
 3 | Material discharged in hopper: Dest: FURNACE; ; 401 - LIME-LUMP: 993kg; 312 - CALCINE DOLOMIT: 521kg; 
 4 | Dest: FURNACE; AUTO; 401 - LIME-LUMP: 993kg; 312 - CALCINE DOLOMIT: 521kg;                            
 5 | Material discharged in hopper: Dest: FURNACE; ; 400 - LIME-LUMP: 1007kg;                              
 6 | Dest: FURNACE; AUTO; 400 - LIME-LUMP: 1007kg;
```

I want to extract numbers for `LIME-LUMP` and `CALCINE DOLOMIT` and show in separate columns like this:

```
ID | CALCINE DOLOMIT| LIME-LUMP                                                                                                   |
-- | -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1 | 1505           |0                   
 2 | 1505           |0                                               
 3 | 993            |521 
 4 | 993            |521                      
 5 | 0              |1007                             
 6 | 0              |1007
```

I wrote this query:

```
select id,txt,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '\d+', 1, 2) AS CALCINE_DOLOMIT,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, '\d+', 1, 4) AS LIME_LUMP 
from tbl1
```

but this query returns the `Lime Lump` value for `Calcine dolomit` sometimes...

After extracting the values I want to move row 2,4,6 (TXT column has `Dest:` string) To `DEST id` column like this:

```
ID | CALCINE DOLOMIT| LIME-LUMP |DEST id
-- | --------------------------------------
 1 | 1505           |0          |2                                            
 3 | 993            |521        |4   
 5 | 0              |1007       |6
```

Please help me...

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=af9dcbf92c68963df5408e17e6348274)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the results you want with this query. It uses a CTE to extract the `CALCINE_DOLOMIT` and `LIME_LUMP` values from the source using [`REGEXP_SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303), then `JOIN`s that back to the original table on rows which match the extracted values and start with `Dest:`

```
WITH CTE AS (
  SELECT Id, 
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, 'CALCINE DOLOMIT: (\d+)', 1, 1, '', 1) AS CD,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(txt, 'LIME-LUMP: (\d+)', 1, 1, '', 1) AS LL
  FROM tbl1
  WHERE txt NOT LIKE 'Dest:%'
)
SELECT CTE.Id, CTE.CD "CALCINE DOLOMIT", CTE.LL "LIME-LUMP", t1.ID "Dest ID"
FROM tbl1 t1
JOIN CTE ON t1.txt LIKE 'Dest:%'
        AND (CTE.CD IS NULL OR REGEXP_LIKE(txt, CONCAT('CALCINE DOLOMIT: ', CTE.CD)))
        AND (CTE.LL IS NULL OR REGEXP_LIKE(txt, CONCAT('LIME-LUMP: ', CTE.LL)))
```

Output:

```
ID  CALCINE DOLOMIT     LIME-LUMP   Dest ID
1   1505                            2
3   521                 993         4
5                       1007        6
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2427bca55de98661d506515c335faff7)